# JavaScript coding challenge - star out grid

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, and I'm doing some coding challenges. I'm given a grid with one star in it. Once you find it, star out everything in that row and column. For example:

```
A B C 
D * E 
F G H
```

would become:

```
A * C
* * *
F * H
```

The grid would be given as an array or arrays. So

```
[ ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', '*', 'E'], ['F', 'G', 'H'] ]
```

should return

```
[ ['A', '*', 'C'], ['*', '*', '*'], ['F', '*', 'H'] ]
```

I can't wrap my head around how to do this. I know we need to loop over the arrays and find the star. But not sure how to turn the whole column and row into stars. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: you could start with a basic loop.

Comment: Think about the (row,column) index of the star when you find it. What are the indices of the values you need to turn into stars after that? (write it out :) )

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Return the [x, y] position of the star
function findStar(grid) {
    // Loop over all of the rows (y axis)
    for (let y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
        // Does the row's columns contain a star?
        // This'll be -1 if there is no star in the row,
        // otherwise it'll be the index of the column that contains the star.
        let x = grid[y].indexOf("*");

        // If we have a star (if not, we'll loop over to the next row)
        if (x > -1) {
            return {x: x, y: y};
        }
    }
}

// Given an [x, y] position and a grid, star out the row and column that
// intersect at the [x, y] position.
function starOut(grid, coords) {

    // Make a copy of the grid (mutation / side effects are bad!)
    // Returning here will of course exit the function and make the
    // outer loop stop running :)
    return grid.map((row, y)=>{
        // Create a clone of the current row in the map
    
        // If it's our current row (the one with the star in it)
        // make the row just all stars
        if (y == coords.y) return new Array(row.length).fill("*");
        
        // If it's not, loop through the row.
        // Return the cell if it's not in the star's column
        // Return a "*" character for that column.
        else return row.map((item, col)=> col == coords.x ? "*" : item);
    });
}

// The function you want, which combines the two tasks together!
function combined(grid) {
    return starOut(grid, findStar(grid));
}
```

Building this code yourself, a useful approach is to split it up into tasks.

Think: am I going to be able to create the output without knowing the (x, y) position of the `*` character? The answer is of course no, so this is out first task: to find that position.

The second task is obvious: given an (x, y) position, star out the given row and column. My original version of this answer put both of these tasks together in one function, but to show this point it actually makes more sense to split them apart into seperate functions, as shown above.

It's worth noting here that you can actually do these tasks independantly of each other: if you find one of them easier than the other, you can start by writing that one, and then testing it.

For example, I could write the `starOut` function first, passing in the grid and say `{x: 1, y: 1}` as the parameter to test it out, without having written `findStar` yet.

---

That aside, hopefully you find the code example useful, and hopefully the comments explain what actually happens on each line. In the real world, you shouldn't actually comment that much (think of them more as a Director's commentary on a movie, rather than a blow-by-blow what happens on a line), but on StackOverflow I want to make sure you do actually literally understand each line.

Another paradigm worth mentioning here, which is different to what occurs in @Hasan's answer, is that we don't *mutate* the array. This means, we create an entirely new array, rather than changing the old one. Trying to avoid mutating the stuff we're given is a good habit to get into, as it can often cause problems later down the line.

Finally, I realise you might not have had too much exposure to the `.map` method on arrays. It (and it's friends `.reduce`, `.filter`, etc) are very useful for these kinds of tasks. I'd recommend reading the MDN articles around these functions --- here's the map one as a good starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

---

If you're just looking for the code, without any of the learning aids, here it is:

```
function starOutGrid(grid) {
    for (let y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
        let x = grid[y].indexOf("*");
        if (x > -1) {
            return grid.map((row, i)=>{
                if (i == y) return new Array(row.length).fill("*");
                else return row.map((item, col)=> col == x ? "*" : item);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work with nested loops, but I wanna try this too. How can I change this to get it to work with multiple stars and non-square grids?

Comment: @EA6923 For multiple stars: You could easily modify `findStar` to be `findAllStars` --- when it finds one it just adds it to an array rather than returning it, and then returns the array at the end. Then, in our `combined` function, we loop over the array of coords and call `starOut` on each one, passing in the grid created by the last. Seperating them into functions which work independantly has really helped us out here!

Comment: As for non-square grids: I'm pretty certain my version already works on those :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [ ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', '*', 'E'], ['F', 'G', 'H'] ] 
let row, col;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if(arr[i][j] === "*") {
         row = i;
         col = j;
      }
   }
}

arr[row].fill("*"); // fill that row with "*"

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // fill that column with "*"
   arr[i][col] = "*";
}
```

I think above code will solve your problem. In JavaScript it has lots of functions which gets easier your problems. Therefore, maybe you can start with this amazing document:
[MDN Javascript Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: Thank you very much. How would I change this to work with multiple stars and non-square grids? It also crashes and returns a typeerror if there are no stars. (fill of undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in posts above, there are lots of methods to do this.
Here I just wanted to show that there is basically a 1 line solution in finding the "*" inside the arrays.
The way of starring out I took from Hasan Brasi's post, as it is simple and complete.

```js
let arr = [ ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', '*', 'E'], ['F', 'G', 'H'] ] 

// find
let col, row = arr.findIndex(x => (col = x.indexOf("*")) !== -1);

// add *'s
if(row !== -1){
  // fill row with *
  arr[row].fill("*");
  // fill cols with *
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i][col] = "*";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work with nested loops, but I wanna try this too. How can I change this to get it to work with multiple stars and non-square grids?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this as a 2 step process.

#1. Looping over the nested array to find out if there is indeed a star located in each array. If so, make that row all stars. Also, save the star index location to a variable and push to an empty array for later use. If there are no stars, leave it unchanged.

```
   const grid = [["A","B","C"],["D","*","F"],["G","H","I"]];

   const starIndex = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {

      if (grid[i].includes("*")) {
         const star = grid[i].indexOf("*")
         starIndex.push(star);
         grid[i].fill("*")
      }
   }
```

#2. Now that we have our rows displaying stars where applicable, we can focus on the columns of stars that need to be implemented. We can do this with another loop. This time we loop over the array we created to store our star location index(or indices). Then we run an inner for loop to loop over all grid arrays and change the index (or indices) to the corresponding location based off of our saved star index (or indices).

```
    for (let i = 0; i < starIndex.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
             grid[j][starIndex[i]] = "*";
          }
       }
       return grid;
    }
```

This is also dynamic as this will work for multiple rows and columns. Also for multiple stars in the nested array argument.